# Automated conversion to real accented characters

Tags: org-mode, org-export, unicode, characters, org-ref

I use `org-mode` to maintain a to-read list of articles. An entry in the list is produced by a function that I wrote in ELisp. The function uses `bibtex-completion-get-value` for the title and `bibtex-completion-apa-get-value` for the authors of the article.

Currently, an entry can look like this:

```
* UNREAD  "Fast and Almost Optimal Any-Angle Pathfinding Using the 2\({}^{\mbox{k}}\) Neighborhoods" by Hormaz\'abal, Nicol\'as, D\'\iaz, Antonio, Hern\'andez, Carlos, & Baier, J. A.
```

To be able to correctly export this list to latex/pdf (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123710/111587) reply), I would like to automatically replace `\'a` for `á`, `\'\i` for `í` etc. in the string returned by `bibtex-completion-apa-get-value`.

Can I achieve this without having to explicitly handle [each possible accented character](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes)? (which would be considerably more complicated than [this code](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_zap_gremlins.html), since the mapped keys would need to be *strings* such as `"\'\i"`)

Comment: For now, the best thing I found is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580132/2725810. I'll need to write a short python script to make a map for ELisp.

Comment: You may also check [this project](https://github.com/clarkgrubb/latex-input) which has elisp code for latex input.